# DataGridView Cell color change

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a test program that builds a datatable (26 rows by 6 cols) as datasource for a DataGridView.
The datagrid can be edited by selecting cells, and entering values from one of 3 NumUpDown controls.
Each control has specific color. To preserve the information, I save the table in user settings.
I keep the color information for each cell in extra table cells.
Problem: When I display the datagrid it reads OK the values from the table, but the cell colors that are supposed to be programatically added based on the extra cells info, do not show.
(I can see in diagnostics that the cells get the correct colors, but it does not show in the datagrid.
Looks like the datagird has some color override (?).
Attached is the full working code.
See more info in the code.
Can anyone be kind to run this and find why the colors are not shown in the datagrid?
Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//This is a test program to do the following:
//1. Build an empty data table of 26 rows by 6 columns.
//2. The Table is bind (as DataSource) to a DataGridView.
//3. The DataGrid Colomns 0-3 can be filled with decimals by one of 3 NumericUpDown  controls.
//3. For each cell in cols 0-2 there is one in cols 3-5 that holds info which NumUpDn  was used.
//4. Each NumUpDn has specific color. The corresponding cells have the same backcolor.
//5. When the program starts, it builds the table from the Settings, and displays the  table in the datagrid.
//6. The cells in cols 0-2 are supposed to get the colors ad indicated in cols 3-5, but   they do not.
//To run, make a WinForm with a datagrid 'fareGrid' and 3 NumUpDn controls with background colors.  


namespace DataGridViewTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable fareTable = new DataTable();

    int rowIndex;
    int colIndex;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buildFareTable("fareTable");
        // Load the table (if exists)
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.fareTable != null)
            fareTable = Properties.Settings.Default.fareTable;
        paintFareTableCells(fareTable);

    }

    //Build the initial data table of 26R X 6C
    //Columns 3-5 are used to hold the color information of cols 0-2
    public void buildFareTable(string fareTableName)
    {
        fareTable.TableName = fareTableName;
        fareTable.Columns.Add("Weekday", typeof(Decimal));
        fareTable.Columns.Add("HalfDay", typeof(Decimal));
        fareTable.Columns.Add("Weekend", typeof(Decimal));

        //Adding 3 indexing columns that will hold the tables cell group
        fareTable.Columns.Add("IWeekday", typeof(String));
        fareTable.Columns.Add("IHalfDay", typeof(String));
        fareTable.Columns.Add("Iweekend", typeof(String));

        for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 26; rowIndex++)
        {
            fareTable.Rows.Add();
        }
    }

    public void paintFareTableCells(DataTable fareTable)
    {
        fareDataGrid.DataSource = fareTable;

        for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 26; rowIndex++)
        {
            for (colIndex = 0; colIndex < 3; colIndex++)
            {
                switch (fareTable.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex + 3].ToString())   //Check the color index columns 3-5
                {
                    case "low": fareDataGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;  
                        break;
                    case "med": fareDataGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow; 
                        break;
                    case "high": fareDataGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;  
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                // Diagnostics: Check cell's color. At this point, Colors are OK!  
                Color color = fareDataGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor;  
            }
        }
    }

   //Update the cells by 3 NumUpDn controls.
    private void numericUpDownFareHigh_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        editFareTableCells(sender);
    }
    private void numericUpDownFareMed_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        editFareTableCells(sender);
    }

    private void numericUpDownFareLow_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        editFareTableCells(sender);
    }

    public void editFareTableCells(Object sender)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in fareDataGrid.SelectedCells)
        {
            if (cell.ColumnIndex < 3)
            {
                cell.Value = ((NumericUpDown)sender).Value;
                cell.Style.BackColor = ((NumericUpDown)sender).BackColor;
                fareDataGrid[cell.ColumnIndex + 3, cell.RowIndex].Value = ((NumericUpDown)sender).Tag;   //Uses cols 3-5 to hold cost level info.
            }
        }
    }

    //Use settings to preserve the data
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.fareTable = this.fareTable;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The color-changing code must be in an event handler; specifically, the `DataBindingComplete` event handler. I re-wrote your code as follows:

```
public void paintFareTableCells(DataTable fareTable)
{
    fareDataGrid.DataSource = fareTable;
}

void fareDataGrid_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 26; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (colIndex = 0; colIndex < 3; colIndex++)
        {
            switch (fareTable.Rows[rowIndex][colIndex + 3].ToString())   //Check the color index columns 3-5
            {
                case "low":
                    fareDataGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    break;
                case "med":
                    fareDataGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    break;
                case "high":
                    fareDataGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            // Diagnostics: Check cell's color. At this point, Colors are OK!  
            Color color = fareDataGrid[colIndex, rowIndex].Style.BackColor;
        }
    }
}
```

The cells now change color based on values, as desired.

By the way, don't forget to subscribe to the event handler in your constructor:

```
fareDataGrid.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(fareDataGrid_DataBindingComplete);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `paintFareTableCells`, it is likely that the case statement is falling through to the `default` and thus not setting any value. Confirm this with a break point and amend your column index accordingly.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the case.   
As I indicated, I tested with breakpoints, and added a line that reads back the colors in each cell. They are all OK.   
Problem is that when I close and re-run the program, the table is fine, all commands are executed, the cells have the correct values,  but the cell back color display is still all white, although I can see in the properties that they are colored.   
It looks like something in the program removes the colors after they are set, and before the grid is displayed.   
Any idea?   Thanks

Comment: The `Backcolor` of cells in a `DataGridView` does _not_ persist between application restarts. You may have invoked a save mechanism for the cell values, but you will need to re-color the cells.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware that Tables do not have cell color property, thus color can not be preserved.
For that very reason, as you may have seen in the code, I do recolor the cells for each restart. It is part of the code.
The problem is that although the cell backcolor properties, as seen in debug (and as read back in the extra line I added) are OK, but the table is displayed colorless, which is my actual problem.
Have tried Style.Apply and other options, for no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I am not sure why your cells are not being painted as they should be, but my best guess would be the fact you're trying to change their property before they handle their paint event.
I managed to change colors of cells with event, as Joe Sisk suggested, and it works fine for me. I hope it helps you. The difference is I used CellPainting event, here's short version of what I did, I hope it helps you to figure the rest yourself...

```
    private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null) // if condition is met, this cell will be painted
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black; // i used black color, feel free to replace it :)
        }
    }
```

I hope this works for you?